# How do I negate a query in Parse's API (Back4App)? Specifically, how do I get everything not in a relation?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to negate a parse query? Something like this:

```
Parse.Query.not(query)
```

More specifically I want to do a relational query that gets everything except for the objects within the query. For example:

```
const relation = myParseObject.relation("myRelation");
const query = relation.query();
const negatedQuery = Parse.Query.not(query);
return await negatedQuery.find();
```

I know one solution would be to fetch the objects in the relation and then create a new query by looping through the objectIds using `query.notEqualTo("objectId", fetchedObjectIds[i])`, but this seems really circuitous...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you need to return. If you can share some information about your schema and an example of what you want to retrieve, I can try to help. Anyways, it looks that `doesNotMatchKeyInQuery` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

`doesNotMatchKeyInQuery` is the solution as Davi Macedo pointed out in the comments.

For example, if I wanted to get all of the Comments that are not in an Article's relation, I would do the following:

```
const relationQuery = article.relation("comments").query();
const notInRelationQuery = new Parse.Query("Comment");
notInRelationQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", relationQuery);
const notRelatedComments = await notInRelationQuery.find();
```

How I understand it is that the first argument is specifying the key in the objects that we are fetching. The second argument is specifying the key in the objects that are in the query that we're about to argue. And lastly we argue a query for the objects we don't want. So, it essentially finds the objects you don't want and then compares the values of the objects you do want to the values of the objects you don't want for the argued keys. It then returns all the objects you do want. I could probably write that more succinctly, but w/e.